# Remote-Debugging in Running Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging

We are trying to add a new page to a running web application. such that a new dll and aspx file are being added. I've setup break points in the code file and Built the application transfering the dll to the remote machine bin file and the aspx page to a folder within the web application. Note this folder is not in the same folder hierarchy as it built in. I'm not sure if thats the problem. Basically we are appending new functionality to a web application.

I've completed the following

1. I've copied the correct Remote Debug Monitor to the server and have it running.
2. I'm able to attach to the process which in this case is w3wp.exe (I've Identified that it is the correct process for my application.
3. I deployed the *.dll to the the bin folder with the *.pdb file along with it.
4. I've deployed the *.aspx file to the location we want.

With the file open in visual studio with breakpoints setup, we attach to the process and debug. I get 'No symbols loaded' and the breakpoint go empty.

I'm missing something it seems. I've searched the net but have only found complete publish\ deployment scenario.

Any thoughts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Symbols -> Add the path to your deployed web application dlls and pdbs.

You might also need to uncheck "Enable Just My Code" under general debugging.

Here's a more detailed answer that got it working for me in the past: [Remote Debugging is not breaking on errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466969/remote-debugging-is-not-breaking-on-errors)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a bunch. I've been scratching my head on this one for awhile.